# How to have left and right spacing between table rows and table edge?

Tags: html, css, sass

This is the desired effect:[image]

And this is what I came up with: http://jsfiddle.net/nunoarruda/3j6782js/

```
// table
.sw-table {
  border-collapse: separate;

  thead {
    background-color: $orange;
    color: $white;
    font-size: 15px;

    th {
      border: none !important;
      font-weight: 600;
      padding-top: 5px !important;
      padding-bottom: 5px !important;
      margin: 30px 27px !important;

      &:first-child {
        border-top-left-radius: 10px;
        padding-left: 25px;
      }

      &:last-child {
        border-top-right-radius: 10px;
      }
    }
  }

  tbody {
    color: $black;

    tr {
      td {
        border-color: $greyish;
        padding-top: 10px !important;
        padding-bottom: 10px !important;
      }

      td:first-child {
        border-left: 1px solid $greyish;
        padding-left: 25px;
      }

      td:last-child {
        border-right: 1px solid $greyish;
      }

      &:first-child td {
        border-top: none;
      }

      &:last-child td {
        border-bottom: 1px solid $greyish;

        &:first-child {
           border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
        }

        &:last-child {
          border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

It's just missing the space between the table row and the table border. I've tried using margin, padding, border, border-collapse but I couldn't achieve the desired effect. Any ideias?

Comment: Styling tables, especially table rows are notoriously tough to style. As a result I think you'll end up having to use a solution that is a bit "dirty" like adding extra columns or inserting a DIV inside each table cell.

Comment: I don't think you can set the width of the border ... The content need to be nested in something inside the td and apply the border to it. Or add extra td as suggested by @wlin. You can add an extra row with rowspan that only contains a div with margin-left and right with the border.

Comment: @chipChocolate.py that's not the desired visual effect...

Comment: @chipChocolate.py I think you're missing the point. Check screenshot. I need spacing between the table rows and the table border and not the other way around. But thanks for the effort!

Comment: Jeeeeez! Sorry! My bad, now I realize what you want.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Check this fiddle:](http://jsfiddle.net/austinthedeveloper/3j6782js/6/)

The most important thing I did was wrap the first and last items in divs and styled them:

```
<td>
  <div>Brand name</div>
</td>
```

This allowed me to take off the padding/border of the td and move it to the divs:

```
td:first-child {
  border-left: 1px solid $greyish;
  padding-left: 25px;
  padding-top: 0;
  padding-right: 0;
  border-top: none;
  div {
    border-top: 1px solid $greyish; 
    padding-top: 10px; 
    padding-right: 8px;
  }            
}
```

The last thing I did was remove !important on the padding because that was messing with the new code. The borders are now attached to the divs inside first and last child instead of the tds!

Answer (score 2):

I know this is a dumb hack. but I just put an empty cell in in it. I hope someone have a good solution to this.

http://jsfiddle.net/3j6782js/1/

```
<tr>
        <td class='space'></td>
        <td>Brand name</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>
            <a class='btn btn-purple btn-xs sw-btn' href='#'>MANAGE CAMPAIGNS</a>
            <a class='btn btn-grey btn-xs sw-btn' href='#'>EDIT</a>
        </td>
</tr>

.space {
width:10px !important;
border-top:none !important;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the effort! Indeed this is hacky and not semantic since it requires extra markup to achieve the visual effect but it is something :) I hope someone comes with a CSS only solution.

Comment: Just a thought, if you add `border-left/right` of color white to `tr`, and border the whole table. change `separate` to `collapse`

Comment: border on `tr` overflows, doesn't stay inside the table and has weird behaviour.

Comment: Unfortunately you'll get some artifacts from doing that. The ends of a border meet at 45 degree angles.

Answer (score 2):

How about instead of adding `border` to `td`, you add it to a `span` inside of a `td`. Quick example:

```css
body{
  margin:0;
  padding:10px;
}

table{
  width:100%;
  /* reset */
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0;
}

/* some padding top/bottom for every td */
td{
  padding-top:10px;
  padding-bottom:10px;
  margin:0;
}

/* first and last row border */
table tr:first-child{border-top: 1px solid black}
table tr:nth-child(3){border-bottom: 1px solid black}


/* adding padding to the td's */
table tr>td:first-of-type{padding-left: 10px; padding-right:0; border-left: 1px solid black;padding-left:50px}
table tr>td:nth-of-type(2){padding-left:0;padding-right:0;}
table tr>td:nth-of-type(3){padding-right: 10px; padding-left: 0; border-right: 1px solid black;text-align:right; padding-right: 50px;}

/* adding border to spans */
table tr>td:first-of-type>span{border-bottom: 1px solid black; display:block;}
table tr>td:nth-of-type(2)>span{border-bottom: 1px solid black; display:block;}
table tr>td:nth-of-type(3)>span{border-bottom: 1px solid black; display:block;}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td><span>11</span></td>
    <td><span>12</span></td>
    <td><span>13</span></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><span>21</span></td>
    <td><span>22</span></td>
    <td><span>23</span></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><span>31</span></td>
    <td><span>32</span></td>
    <td><span>33</span></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vucko/mj7uq7vL/2)

I'm adding `padding` to the `td`, and using `display:block` to `spans` inside of `td` so they would get all the width.

Answer (score 0):

I would simply add a horizontal rule (`<hr>`) between rows:

```
<tr><td colspan="3"><hr>
```

If you style the `hr`, it will have minimal impact on your layout:

```
hr {
  background: #ddd;
  height: 1px;
  margin: 0px;
}
```

Not exactly [semantic](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/hr.html), but it gets the job done.

### Fiddle

Note that I've removed the `table` class from the table, because it's not defined in your style sheet, so it's picking up jsFiddle's styling instead.